# LinAlg based physics textbooks

Tags: resource-recommendations, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I'm in my second year studying physics, and ever since I took LinAlg, I've been noticing LinAlg-related concepts pop up all over the place, but it has never been presented directly as matrices, bases, etc.

For instance, I want to understand what an eigenstate- or frequency has to do with matrix eigenvalues. I want to know why we use sin and cos in Fourier analysis (it's a basis, but for which vector space, etc.). I find LinAlg elegant and compact, and I want to know what formal classical mechanics, special relativity, analytical mechanics, QM and EM (and statistical mechanics if possible) looks like using LinAlg to accomplish general and rigid derivations of the concepts involved.

Tensor notation might also be acceptable, even though I have no experience with it yet.

Any suggestions for textbooks/texts that might help?

EDIT: I don't see how this is a question about how QM relates to/uses LinAlg? There is one textbook reference in the answers for that other question, and it only refers to one chapter.

Comment: Hi Lovsovs: Res. recom. questions, which often tend to become  _primarily opinion-based_ list questions, are strictly regulated on Phys.SE, cf. various meta posts. Lin. alg. penetrates every area of physics, so this question seems also _too broad._ I close it as a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.

Comment: All right, and which direction is that?